# Fan Forced Garage Heater blowing 3A fuse

Tags: furnace, circuit, board

Mr. Heater forced air heater that is blowing the 3a fuse instantly. Supply voltage is good, transformer secondary is 27v. Removed stat wires off control board, still blows fuse on powering up. Checked all wires to look for nicks/shorts/poor connections. Could this be a bad board?

Comment: Does the fan motor spin freely?

Comment: Search for the short

Comment: Check all the fan power wiring, you probably have a ground fault where a bare wire is touching the frame. The results are the same if it is shorted to the neutral. If anything is bad I would take a SWAG and say it is the blower motor.

Comment: Can you post the wiring diagram for your unit please?